# How to count results with a filter using Slick?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scalaquery, slick

I face a problem I would like to simplify : (quite sure, I'm doing it wrong in fact).

#### Wanted

I would like to count the number of users having an id = 1. In SQL language let's say it is something like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = 1
```

#### Code

I'm using Slick in it's "lifted" form, so here is my piece of code counting the users :

```
Query(Users.where( _.id === 1).length).first
```

Actually what happens here is that Slick alias ScalaQuery, is actually creating a subquery with the filter cause and then counting the results of the sub-request.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1))
```

Seems like pretty big overhead for such a query.

Comment: Which DB are you using? Does this really lead to a different query execution plan than `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = 1)`? SQL is based on relational algebra for a reason... you can automatically optimize stuff like this easily. Doesn't mean it's always done though. So IS IT a pretty big overhead or does it just seem like one but is not?

Comment: @cvogt It makes a difference in MySQL 5.6 & Slick 2.1.0.  `TableQuery[MyTable].filter(_.id === 6L).length` returns two nested selects (ie worse than this post), and results in a worse query plan. Is there a better way to tell Slick `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE id = 6` ?

Comment: Here is a hack to override the SQL code Slick uses: https://gist.github.com/cvogt/d9049c63fc395654c4b4

Comment: @cvogt Thanks for the code! :) I was hoping for a hack-free technique - alas!

Comment: No hack free technique available at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this has changed from ScalaQuery to Slick, but try:

```
val q = for{ 
  id <- Parameters[Int]
  t <- tableObject if t.id is id
} yield t.id.count

val cnt = q(someID).firstOption getOrElse 0
```

Comment: Aaaand, there goes my one-liner! Any way, thanks, this indeed seems to work great. The generated SQL query is simpler and syntax is exactly the same for Slick.

Comment: right, I never got in the habit of using Query(...), as unlike for{...}, afaik, Query(...) is not composable (not sure if cached prepared statement is generated under the hood either). At any rate the vast majority of hand written sql can be replicated in SQ/Slick, so happy days ;-) and with type providers on the road map, bye, bye case class companion object mapping boilerplate...

Comment: This might work to check if the result is 0 or 1 but it doesn't seem to work to get the count of items that match a criteria. The result will be a list that I can't figure out what represent. Example: I run it and I expect a count of 5 elements (returned as 1 row with 1 value equal to 5). Instead I get 5 rows each containing one value equal to 3.

Comment: @CristianVrabie firstOption should return an Option, not a List. If you're on Slick, I have no idea, still (happily) on ScalaQuery here.

Comment: @virtualeyes My mistake there. Your exact example does work even on Slick but it gives a deprecated warning on the `.count` method saying to replace it with `.length`. When you do it behaves as I explained. Must be a naming collision with some other function as I've seen many people complaining that the new method does not work as expected.