# Scala Slick 0.11.2 count with H2

Tags: scala, h2, slick

I tried to build a count query with an sample DB from https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/examples/lifted/FirstExample.scala :

```
// Definition of the SUPPLIERS table
object Suppliers extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)]("SUPPLIERS")        {
  def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street = column[String]("STREET")
  def city = column[String]("CITY")
  def state = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip = column[String]("ZIP")
  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * = id ~ name ~ street ~ city ~ state ~ zip
}

// Definition of the COFFEES table
object Coffees extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)]("COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def supID = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def sales = column[Int]("SALES")
  def total = column[Int]("TOTAL")
  def * = name ~ supID ~ price ~ sales ~ total
  // A reified foreign key relation that can be navigated to create a join
  def supplier = foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, Suppliers)(_.id)
}

// Connect to the database and execute the following block within a session
Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1", driver = "org.h2.Driver") withSession {

  (Suppliers.ddl ++ Coffees.ddl).create

  // Insert some suppliers
  Suppliers.insert(101, "Acme, Inc.",      "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199")
  Suppliers.insert( 49, "Superior Coffee", "1 Party Place",    "Mendocino",    "CA", "95460")
  Suppliers.insert(150, "The High Ground", "100 Coffee Lane",  "Meadows",      "CA", "93966")

  // Insert some coffees (using JDBC's batch insert feature, if supported by the DB)
  Coffees.insertAll(
    ("Colombian",         101, 7.99, 0, 0),
    ("French_Roast",       49, 8.99, 0, 0),
    ("Espresso",          150, 9.99, 0, 0),
    ("Colombian_Decaf",   101, 8.99, 0, 0),
    ("French_Roast_Decaf", 49, 9.99, 0, 0)
  )

  /**** This part works fine */
  val query = for (c <- Coffees) yield c
  query foreach println
  /*********/

  /******This one fails */
  val query1 = for (c <- Coffees) yield c.length
  println("query1 = " + query1.list.head)
```

The error H2 raised was:

```
    Column "X4.COF_NAME" not found; SQL statement:
    CREATE FORCE VIEW PUBLIC._1 AS
    SELECT
        X4.COF_NAME,
        X4.SUP_ID,
        X4.PRICE,
        X4.SALES,
        X4.TOTAL
    FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(1, 1) [42122-168]
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "X4.COF_NAME" not found; SQL statement:
    CREATE FORCE VIEW PUBLIC._1 AS
    SELECT
        X4.COF_NAME,
        X4.SUP_ID,
        X4.PRICE,
        X4.SALES,
        X4.TOTAL
    FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(1, 1) [42122-168]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:138)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:799)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepare(Parser.java:202)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepare(Session.java:388)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepare(Session.java:375)
        at org.h2.table.TableView.compileViewQuery(TableView.java:99)
        at org.h2.table.TableView.initColumnsAndTables(TableView.java:144)
        at org.h2.table.TableView.init(TableView.java:95)
        at org.h2.table.TableView.(TableView.java:61)
        at org.h2.table.TableView.createTempView(TableView.java:420)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1037)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1690)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1797)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1684)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1527)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1026)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1690)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1797)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1684)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1527)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1515)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1109)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:74)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:626)
        at scala.slick.session.Session$class.prepareStatement(Session.scala:29)
        at scala.slick.session.BaseSession.prepareStatement(Session.scala:201)
        at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:29)
        at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.elementsTo(StatementInvoker.scala:17)
        at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.foreach(Invoker.scala:90)
        at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.foreach(StatementInvoker.scala:10)
        at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.build(Invoker.scala:66)
        at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.build(StatementInvoker.scala:10)
        at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.list(Invoker.scala:56)
        at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.list(StatementInvoker.scala:10)
        at scala.slick.jdbc.UnitInvoker$class.list(Invoker.scala:150)
        at scala.slick.driver.BasicInvokerComponent$QueryInvoker.list(BasicInvokerComponent.scala:19)
```

Is due to a wrong usage? Is it a bug?

The error is raised if I use

```
println("query1 = " + query1.firstOption.getOrElse(0))
```

as well...

Comment: The statement sent to the database is included in the error message. The table `SYSTEM_RANGE(1, 1)` is a virtual table, very similar to the Oracle table `DUAL`. It only knows the column `X` (not `COF_NAME` and so on).

Comment: @ThomasMueller I have no problem to understand what's wrong at the JDBC level. I just want to query the total number of records in a table with the Slick framework (an extremely basic case) and it fails because it seems the framework doesn't generate properly the expected SQL.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I don't know Slick, so the only way I could help was to explain the meaning of the SQL exception...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```scala
val query1 = for (c <- Coffees) yield c.name.count
println("query1 = " + query1.firstOption.getOrElse(0))
```

The recipe behind it is `c.primary-key.count`; in this case, `name` is the primary key of `Coffees`.

Comment: Had the same problem a week ago, glad it helped. – For the sake of completeness, here's a post covering the case of a parametrized count: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12862963/734191